# Automatic restart of a Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud Platform. The Kubernetes cluster contains a deployment which has one pod. The pod has two containers. I have observed that the pod has been replaced by a new pod and the entire data is wiped out. I am not able to identify the reason behind it.

I have tried the below two commands:

1. `kubectl logs [podname] -c [containername] --previous`

**Result: ** `previous terminated container [containername] in pod [podname] not found`

2. `kubectl get pods`

**Result:** I see that the number of restarts for my pod equals 0.

Is there anything I could do to get the logs from my old pod?

Comment: Don't you have any logs in stackdriver?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't seem to have stackdriver logs

Comment: This is stange, container restarting should fully restart the pods, I never saw a case where a container restart didn't trigger pod restart.

Comment: The pod itself did restart. I think my question was not clear. I'll edit it

Comment: Ok, so did you try to describe your pod to get some input about the error?

Comment: I tried kubectl get pods. The old pod did not show up in the list of pods :( . There is a new pod in my deployment which has replaced the old pod. I see only the new pod in the list

Comment: I meant kubectl describe [POD] as a command :)

Comment: Could you please show your deployment file, so we can better understand the question?

Comment: https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-network-on-kubernetes/blob/master/configFiles/peersDeployment.yaml


This is my deployment file

Comment: Not sure if this your situation, but your pods should be resilient to being restarted at arbitrary points. If they still need data the previous pod created, you should be using a persistent volume to achieve that rather than avoiding restarts altogether

Comment: Also, if you do mind losing your logs (which is normally the case, unless you don't care about the past), you should configure centralized log collection and persistence. `kubectl logs` & `docker logs` is just not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command to see the pod info
kubectl describe po

Answer (score 0):

Not many chances you will retrieve this information, but try next:

1) If you know your failed container id  - try to find old logs here

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/<container id>/<container id>-json.log
```

2) look at kubelet's logs:

```
journalctl -u kubelet
```